# Unexpected Exceptions: System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, sqlconnection

using c#, .Net Framework 4.5

Try to crete simple programm with next code:

```
 enum DataProvider { Sqlserver, Obdc, Oledb, None }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("simple database connection factory");
        IDbConnection Idbc = GetConnection(DataProvider.Sqlserver);
        Console.WriteLine("your connection - {0}", Idbc.GetType().Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static IDbConnection GetConnection(DataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        IDbConnection connection = null;
        switch (dataProvider)
        {
            case DataProvider.Sqlserver:
                connection = new SqlConnection();
                break;
            case DataProvider.Oledb:
                connection = new OleDbConnection();
                break;
            case DataProvider.Obdc :
                connection = new OdbcConnection();
                break;
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

First time it's run ok - gor required result, but now get `Exceptions: System.TypeInitializationException` on string `connection = new SqlConnection();`.

See help in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242144%28v=VS.120,d=hv.2%29.aspx) but can find only `When a class initializer fails to initialize a type, a TypeInitializationException is created and passed a reference to the exception thrown by the type's class initializer` But whats is reason for fail to initialize a type? why first time it's runned ok and second time i got error?

Comment: Did you check the InnerException?

Comment: i think your connection string is empty can you show us how you are assigning connection?

Comment: @Kirill like that http://dineshmandal.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/validinnerexception_thumb.jpg

Comment: @ Ahmet Kakıcı - found - {System.Configuration.ConfigurationException[1]} - reseting myApp.Config.exe - solve problem, Thanks

Comment: It'd be fine if you write that as an answer and accept it, for later use ;)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by **Ahmet Kakıcı** - check inner exception  - like sown on pic below

[image: Cheking of inner exception]

found, a lot of innered exception and the last one was with description  `{System.Configuration.ConfigurationException[1]}`

Try just reset MyApp.exe.config file (put default values like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

As result - now all it's ok.

Real reason whats happend with .config file - really don't know...